# Django + Google SSO openid

Tags: django, openid

I would like to have my application http://app.acquee.com/designer to accept a google account as a login. I found a bunch of libs for django but most work on top of existing Django authentication system that I do not use. I have my own set of user tables where I keep user info and privileges.

Any suggestion on how to integrate that with the Google Openid?

Seems I will have to do it manually using python-openid. Or could I use [django-openid](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid/)?
However, with the latter, I don't even know how to issue the discover command.

Regardless, I get stuck on google's [step 5](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html), sending a login authentication request (optionally with OAuth parameters) to the provided endpoint address. Can someone provide a sample request? is it a GET/POST? content?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth - I'm using it in a commercial project, for both regular Google Accounts and Google Apps accounts. I remember that it was the most convincing one at the time I was doing a review, although I can't give you any details now due to my short memory. Anyway - it's working great.

Comment: Tomasz, are you using it with built in Django authentication or your custom one? As far as I understood, django-openid-auth only works with built in Django user management...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that part about not using Django user system. Writing this - why are you not using it? You can always use custom user profiles to store any additional data you might need. And if you really don't want to use `django.contrib.auth`, then yes, you probably have to go the low-level way and speak directly to python-openid (or django-openid, but I'm not sure of this one, never used it, just quickly scanned its source code).